# How to design fast/efficient algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

Let's say, if you could travel to the past, what would you teach your younger self? Which key points define efficient algorithms?

Comment: That depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This sounds like it might be too broad to me.  Any community votes?

Comment: Have fun. (Gets harder.)

Comment: (@D.W.: I am not happy with "use as few resources as possible" to begin with. What does/should *efficient* mean is an excellent question, if hard and broad.)(The first sentence looks of topic.)

Answer (score 2):

The whole "how to design efficient algorithms" theme is (surprise!) treated in books usually called ["Algorithms"](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms) or sometimes a variation like ["Introduction to Algorithms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). Areas of active research (some more advanced textbooks available) are approximation algorithms (get a decent, not the best possible, solution with reasonable cost) and probabilistic algorithms (surprisingly, many hard problems can be best solved --often, not always-- by tossing a coin and using the result to guide the algorithm's decisions). It is a *vast* area.

Important techniques, that are widely applicable, include **greedy algorithms** (divide the solution into steps, at each step take the most promising alternative; almost never works, but when it does, it is hard to beat), **general graph search** (depth first, breadth first, various heuristic variants like $A^*$), **dynamic programming** (like greedy algorithms, but consider several alternatives for each step, save partial solutions for reuse), **divide and conquer** (divide a large problem into several smaller ones of the same type, solve recursively and combine).

But there are scores of specialized algorithms that don't fall into any of the above categories, based on insight into the problem's particular structure.

As Euclid is widely reported to have said, "There is no royal road to mathematics". Or algorithms.